# GCD: asynchronously wait for condition

Tags: ios, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

In my iOS app, I would like to wait for a condition to become true before updating the UI.
I am doing like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
  while (!condition) NSLog("waiting for the condition");
  dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue, ^{
    //update the UI here
  });
});
```

The code above works just fine but I would like to ask if using the *while* loop to do the waiting job is good or not, and if there is any better way.
Thanks!

---Update

The condition is actually a combination of 4 BOOL variables. Each variable associates with a request for content from the server. I'm using AFNetworking framework. In the completion block of each of the 4 requests, I will set the associated BOOL variable to YES.
So, the actual while loop is like this:

```
while (!([MyRequest request1].isFinished && [MyRequest request2].isFinished && [MyRequest request3].isFinished && [MyRequest request4].isFinished)) NSLog("waiting for the condition");
```

Comment: Can you give us a less abstract example? What precisely is this `condition` that you want to check? Different scenarios suggest different approaches (semaphores, KVO, repeating `NSTimer`, `CADisplayLink`, etc.). But this `while` loop approach is not generally advisable.

Comment: I was just trying to simplify the question but that made my question even worse. Just update the detail, @Rob.

Comment: That helps immensely. In that case, I'd just create a new operation, and make it dependent upon those other four request operations. See revised answer. (FYI, this effectively performs KVO on the `isFinished` property of those four operations.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the revised question, it sounds like you have four `AFNetworking` operations that you want to be dependent upon. That's far easier. You might just add a new operation, and make it dependent upon the other four operations:

```
NSOperation *operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        // update UI
    }];
}];

[operation addDependency:requestOneOperation];
[operation addDependency:requestTwoOperation];
[operation addDependency:requestThreeOperation];
[operation addDependency:requestFourOperation];

[queue addOperation:operation];
```

The [`addDependency`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004591-RH2-SW2) mechanism essentially does KVO of `isFinished` of each of those other four operations for you. It's one of the joys of using an `NSOperation`-based framework like AFNetworking. This sort of dependency is really easy to do.

---

Original answer:

If you had to do this, you might use a semaphore instead, e.g., you'd create a semaphore:

```
dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
```

You'd have your async block wait for that:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore);
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue, ^{
        //update the UI here
    });
});
```

And when the condition is satisfied, the code that would have otherwise set this condition flag would, instead:

```
dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
```

Having said that, I'd rather not see a queue blocked (even a concurrent global queue) like this unless absolutely necessary. If that other code could issue the semaphore signal, I'm not sure why it couldn't just initiate the UI update itself. If I did use this semaphore technique, at the very least I'd have this waiting process taking place on a queue of my own creation, not a global queue.

---

Another approach which you can use in many situations, and which I'd probably prefer, is to employ [key value observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html):

For example, I could observe the changing of they `someProperty` property of an object called `obj` like so:

```
[obj addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"someProperty" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

I would then implement `observeValueForKeyPath`:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"someProperty"])
    {
        NSLog(@"update UI here");
    }
}
```

Whenever the `someProperty` property of my `obj` object is updated, my `observeValueForKeyPath` method would be called.

FYI, I'd also make sure that before this object gets released, I'd remove the observer of `obj`:

```
[obj removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"someProperty"];
```

Clearly, this assumes that `someProperty` is [Key Value Coding Compliant](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Compliant.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002172). But if it is, this is a great technique.

Comment: Let say the condition gets updated somewhere that I don't have access to so I can't send the signal with dispatch_semaphore_signal.

Comment: Is the 'queue' in the last statement [queue addOperation:operation]; [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]?

Comment: @ThanhPham Definitely not the main queue. It's a `queue` that you create, e.g. `NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];`. Could be the same queue you added your other four requests, to. Whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

While the general pattern here is correct (Apple refers to it as "call callback"), the `while(!condition)` bit is also known as a "spin lock", and is definitely not the best way to wait for a condition. Consider using `NSTimer` or `NSRunLoop` instead.

Comment: Is it something like this?
while (!condition && [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]);
So the while statement is still there but I guess it won't be a spin lock anymore due to the NSRunLoop part?